# Recovery Suggestion: Attempted to replace extensionless WatchKit app with identifier XXX with extension-based WatchKit app

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch, watchos

I built my watch app in 2017 with the Watch App and Watch App Extension paradigm.  I clicked on the Update to Recommended Settings button in Xcode and now my app will not build to any device and Xcode says "Failed to Install App on Device" with these details:

Any idea how to fix?

```
Failed to install the app on the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 3002
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-09-19 16:51:52 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    NSURL = "file:///Users/garysabo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HockeyTracker-bzwwbvunqeyhycfbxdyveqbugnfv/Build/Products/Debug-watchos/Watch.app/";
}
--
Unable to Install “HockeyTracker”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Attempted to replace extensionless WatchKit app with identifier com.myndarc.HockeyTracker.watchkitapp with extension-based WatchKit app
--
Attempted to replace extensionless WatchKit app with identifier com.myndarc.HockeyTracker.watchkitapp with extension-based WatchKit app
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 153
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle performPreflightWithError:]";
    LegacyErrorString = ReplaceExtensionlessWatchKitAppWithExtensionBasedAppNotAllowed;
    SourceFileLine = 554;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_model" = "Watch6,18";
    "device_osBuild" = "10.0 (21R5355a)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "arm64_32";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 32909;
    "operation_errorCode" = 153;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.3002.IXUserPresentableErrorDomain.1.MIInstallerErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 0;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 2048;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "watchos10.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "10.0";
    "sdk_variant" = watchos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.5.2 (Build 22G91)
Xcode 15.0 (22265) (Build 15A240d)
Timestamp: 2023-09-19T12:51:52-04:00
```

Comment: I didn't change anything but now it builds...not sure what the issue was or why it is working now.